# Forking and reviving an NPM package - do I change the author?

Tags: node.js, npm

I've recently forked and "revived"/updated/fixed an old and unmaintained NPM package.

I uploaded the forked package to the npmjs registry (with my username as the prefix in the name - i.e `@eladavron/name_of_package`) for my own use (and for others to use should they chose), but wasn't sure what's the common practice regarding the "author" entries in the `package.json`.

Do I change it to myself, or do I keep the original author and add myself as a maintainer?

Either way, I wrote in the description that it's a fork of the original package and credited the author, but I wasn't sure what's the common practice in this case.

Answer (score 1):

My own rule is that I add myself as an `author` along the original one (there can be multiple entries) when my contribution reaches 50% of the original code. If there is a dedicated copyright section in the `README`, or license or anything, I keep the original year and add myself with the new time period. For small changes I add myself to the `contributors` section.

This is something that is sometimes governed by the `LICENSE`. In some cases you are explicitly expected to clearly state both your name and the name of the original author.

Comment: Seems like the Author can only be 1 person https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#people-fields-author-contributors

Comment: You can have only one `author` (object type) but multiple `contributors` (array type)